# Arduino-Pico RF433 Rf-Tx cheap modules

Tags: arduino, pi-pico

I currently use Arduino IDE to program Raspberry Pico, using this as reference.
[Arduino-pico Github](https://github.com/earlephilhower/arduino-pico)

My intention, is to use RadioHead library which is not available in MicroPython, to send and receive RF messages through cheap China RF modules.

I used the example code of the RH_ASK library as below, but I cannot see any results printed. Does anyone has tried this? Am I using something wrong?
I have connected RF modules on UART0 pins.

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#ifdef RH_HAVE_HARDWARE_SPI
#include <SPI.h> // Not actually used but needed to compile
#endif

//RH_ASK driver;
RH_ASK driver(2000, 13, 12); 
// RH_ASK driver(2000, 3, 4, 0); // ATTiny, RX on D3 (pin 2 on attiny85) TX on D4 (pin 3 
on attiny85), 
// RH_ASK driver(2000, PD14, PD13, 0); STM32F4 Discovery: see tx and rx on Orange and 
Red LEDS

void setup()
{
#ifdef RH_HAVE_SERIAL
    Serial.begin(9600);   // Debugging only
#endif
    if (!driver.init())
#ifdef RH_HAVE_SERIAL
     Serial.println("init failed");
#else
    ;
#endif
}

void loop()
{   
    uint8_t buf[RH_ASK_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);



    if (driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) // Non-blocking
    {
      driver.recv(buf, &buflen);
        int i;

        // Message with a good checksum received, dump it.
        driver.printBuffer("Got:", buf, buflen);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: How did you build the radiohead library?  How do you know it built correctly.  How did you link your program?

Comment: @:Antifa: Earlier I played the cheap China 433Mhz HC12,  and found that using serial is easier than using SPI. I used MicroPython.  The tutorial I used, and working code: (1) Understanding ... 433MHz Transceiver Module https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/understanding-and-implementing-the-hc-12-wireless-transceiver-module/

(2) Making a Rpi Pico Based Smart Vehicle Part 2 - tlfong01 2021nov03
https://forum.pi-top.com/t/making-a-rpi-pico-based-smart-vehicle-part-2/1104
Section 3. HC12 433MHz RF transceivers, 3.1  uart loop back functions, 3.2  HC12 transmit/receive echo functions.

Comment: @joan, I pressed the upload code on Arduino IDE. On, how I know it built correctly, i am not sure. tell me a way and I will check.

Comment: @tlfong01, you mean that Radio Head uses SPI? So, I have to change the pin to reflect to SPI ones on Pico?

Comment: @Antifa: Ah, there is some misunderstanding. I originally wrote a too long comment and cut it short, causing the confusion. I was saying something like: "HC12 talks UART serial, so it is much more newbie friendly than the once popular but old school now SPI 433MHz RFM12B which I once played in my Arduino days. My apologies for the confusion. Cheers.

Comment: One more thing: I have not experience in RadioHead Library. I only used Win10 Thonny IDE MicroPython to talk to RF12, like one RF12 talking to another RF12, and I found it easy job.